# global sensitivity analysis input and output matrix

Tags: monte-carlo, sensitivity-analysis

I am performing nonlinear analysis in ABAQUS software, with 5 input variables. For each realization of the input vector, I run the code and I get a scalar response value. I am using the Monte Carlo method to generate a sample for the input vector. I generated a Monte Carlo sample of size $N=500000$ for the input vector, and correspondigly I obtained a sample of the same size for the response by running the code. How can I perform a global sensitivity analysis (GSA) without a predefined function for it? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea. We are going to need a lot more information to say anything here.

Comment: for starters, it would help if you would tell us the marginal distributions of the inputs. This sounds like run-of-the-mill Uncertainty Quantification, thus I gather you're modelling the inputs as independent, right?

Comment: ps most likely, with a sample of size 50 the sampling error will be so large that the GSA will easily be misleading, unless one or more inputs contribute way more variance to your output than the others.

Comment: Sorry about before. A mistake was written. 5000000 samples are generated. We can assume all distributions are Normal.

Comment: For isntance, when using once-at-time local sensitivity analysis techniques, we introduce the input and output matrix, and, then, we compute the sensitivity of Y when varying X. based on what I've read, the Sobol's method requires an analytical function. And this is my problem. In ABAQUS, I do not have an an analytical function. There is a way to compute the sensitivity analysis based on the input matrix generated by Monte Carlo and the output matrix?

Comment: so are you running $N=5\cdot10^6$ nonlinear FEM analyses? Sounds like another mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function of $p$ random variables

$$Y=f(X_1,\dots,X_p)$$

When the output is neither a linear nor a monotone function of the outputs, **but** $X_1,\dots,X_p$ are independent, **and** f is square-integrable,  then a good way to estimate the global sensitivity of $Y$ to $X_1,\dots,X_p$ is to use the Sobol indices. The definition of Sobol indices is related to the [ANOVA decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Variance-based_sensitivity_analysis&oldid=714362100)(note this is a permalink). Assuming that you are only interested in the main effect indices and total order indices, and assuming that you are really going to run $N=5\cdot10^6$ nonlinear FEM analyses and storing all the corresponding results (?), you can use `fast99` from the R package `sensitivity`:

```
N <- 10^6
p <- 5
library(sensitivity)
x <- fast99(model = NULL, factors = p, n = N, q = "qnorm", q.arg = list(mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

`x` is an object which, among the other things, stores the design you will need to run, i.e., the $M=pN$ realizations of the input vector, corresponding to the $M$ runs of your code. You can access them with

`x$X`

you can consult the docs of `sensitivity` for additional information. Once you have the $M$ runs of your code, and the corresponding vector of responses `y`, you can update the object `x` with

```
tell(x, y)
```

Now, `S <- x$D1/x$V` and `T <- 1- x$Dt/x$V` are respectively the first-order indices (or main effect indices) and the total order indices.

`fast99` is reasonably fast, as far as non-model based methods for the estimate of Sobol indices go. However, it has two drawbacks:

1. it only gives you a point estimate, but not a confidence interval
2. it can be inaccurate when the Sobol indices are small in magnitude w.r.t. 1, even though with millions of runs this won't be a problem.

An alternative to `fast99`, which is more accurate in the estimation of the smaller indices, but require thrice the number of runs, is `sobolowen`. This returns a Monte-Carlo based estimator of the Sobol indices, thus you get a confidence interval along with the point estimates. In this case you generate 3 design matrices this way:

```
X1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(p * N), nrow = N))
X2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(p * N), nrow = N))
X3 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(p * N), nrow = N))
```

and then, for 95%-confidence interval Monte Carlo estimates of the main effect and total order indices, you call

```
x <- sobolowen(model = NULL, X1, X2, X3, nboot = 100)
```

As before, `x$X` contains your DOE. Update `x` with `tell`, and now `x$S` and `x$T` store respectively the first-order indices and the total order indices. Consult the vignette of `sensitivity` for many other estimators of the Sobol indices, with varying computational efforts.

PS note that here I assumed all your variables to be standard normal. I guess $X_1,\dots,X_p$ are design parameters, whose distributions you assumed normal, but which are likely not standard normal. This means that to obtain your actual DOE, you need to transform each column of `x$X` by multiplying it for the standard deviation of variable $X_i$, and then add the mean of $X_i$.

**EDIT**: I just got the abstract of this paper in my feeds;

http://www.ans.org/pubs/journals/nt/a_38989

It discusses exactly your problem (though I assume their ABAQUS model will be more complex than yours), so you should give it a look. If you cannot access the paper from the above link, these two pdfs seem quite similar, even if a little older (1 year):

https://inldigitallibrary.inl.gov/sti/6468109.pdf

https://inldigitallibrary.inl.gov/sti/6799579.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I think it is better to use the sobolowen. However I have a doubt (I am not a R expert!): I have generated my random values, but not in R (I only have the p*N=M matrix), and for each line I have an output y. According with what you've said, 
N <- 10^6
p <- 5
library(sensitivity)

Comment: N <- 10^6
p <- 5
library(sensitivity)
X1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(p * N), nrow = N))
X2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(p * N), nrow = N))
X3 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(p * N), nrow = N))

Comment: x <- sobolowen(model = NULL, X1, X2, X3, nboot = 100)

Comment: @user3641311 ? I don't understand, what is your doubt?

Comment: tell(x, y)

This is the procedure I must follow, right? But, in the matrix M, I should past my generated samples, right? I looked for x$X, but I cannot find the meaning. Could you explain me please? My obtained values in sobolowen go in x right?

Comment: This is gonna get long, and comments are not for extended discussions. I will create a chat room when I'm at the pc , say, in half an hour, and give you the link.

Comment: Chat built: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46851/computing-sobol-indices-with-the-sensitivity-package. Let me know when you want to chat, I need to authorize you.

Comment: hmmm, I gave you the access. Still not able to chat?

Comment: I have a question: I've generated 100 samples per variable. If I have 5 variables, I will generate 500 samples (total size). However, when I generate x<-fast99.... I got a matrix 500*5!!!! I have 100 responses.. Do I have to run 500 times my model?

Comment: yes, precisely. If you read my answer again, you'll see that I explicitly stated that, for a given discretization level of the sample space $N$, and for a number of predictors (input variables) $p$, the sample size, i.e., the required number of ABAQUS runs using `fast99`, is $M=pN$. I told you about these methods, because initially you said you could run millions of simulations. But if $M=500$ is too much for you, then you need to use metamodels (which is what pretty much everyone working in UQ does). What about asking a new question?

Answer (score 0):

A first approach is to calculate the correlation coefficients between the inputs and output. For a linear model, the sensitivity coefficient is equal to the square of the correlation coefficient. If the input/output relation is not linear but monotonous, use Spearman correlation. 
Otherwise, you will need something like Sobol, which DOES NOT require an analytical model, but only to be able to return an output value for a given input set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, the model is highly nonlinear. So, Sobol will be the best option. For each set of input values, I have an output. But I do not know how to apply Sobol's sensitivity analysis in this situation (no analyhtical function). Could you please point a reference?

Comment: There a many references. Look for instance for "saltelli sensitivity analysis" in your favorite web search engine.